# iOS Handle a memory warning

Tags: ios, memory-management, didreceivememorywarning

I have a `UIViewController` that is shown as a modal view controller. In its view I have an `UITextView`, 4 ImageButtons (with CustomType) and another button (custom type too) which allows to take a photo and then show it in that button.

The problem is next:

1. Suppose I have set some text in the `UITextView` and the 4 ImageButtons have an image in each one of them.
2. Then I launch the `UIImagePickerController` and I  receive a memory warning (what happens usually) so `didReceiveMemoryWarning` gets called and viewDidUnload.
3. When I return from `UIImagePickerController` all the info is cleaned so the user has to retype everything (and set the 4 photos for the buttons).

So the question is, how should i handle this situation in order to avoid user retyping everything? Should i save the state in UserDefaults or store the old info in the properties of the `UIViewController` so use them when the `viewDidLoad` gets called again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to involve NSUserDefaults. Just save the state of the various controls in your view controller's properties. Then you can restore the controls in your `-viewDidLoad` method when the view is reloaded.